# TrueCrypt Corrupted MFT : Can't access data after successful volume header restore

Tags: truecrypt

I'm having a very similar issue here and don't feel confident on attempting to fix it without some knowledgeable guidance, hoping I can get some assistance

Background:

- I mount a volume onto my E partition which displays as D
- Container became unmountable after motherboard driver update
- After restoring the volume header from an external backup I was able to mount
- Then disk showed that it needed to formatted but I was able to overcome that issue.
- I wasn't able to recover any data with GetDataBack, Recuva, or PhotoRec.

Current Problem:

- D: Is Not Accessible :: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/48637/Share...3_14-26-22.jpg
- I mounted the volume and opened it up in Winhex. While there is a lot of random information there are very large blocks of readable information such as chat logs and emails.
- I get this error :: Drive D: Cannot open "$MFT". Unexpected data at offset C0000000 and offset 2000, Res=-9, Res2=-9

I just need a gentle push towards getting MFT restored and it looks like I'll be off and running.

current status [http://i.imgur.com/jvUypaM.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/jvUypaM.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you use Windows Repair Console to repair the MFT?

Comment: Is this a known fix to issues with a TrueCrypt partition that isn't system?  Wouldn't I run the risk of making things even worse? Everything else is working just fine.

Comment: I am stuck in the same boat as you. I've been using TestDisk to no avail. Were you able to recover the data on your drive after restoring the volume header?